# Angular nvd3 interactive guideline show too much data

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am creating a line chart with 3 lines.

First line has data from *dateA* to *dateB*

Second and third lines have data from *dateB* to *dateC*

[image: linechart]

The problem is linked to the interactive guideline. When the mouse is over the first line (dark blue) it should only display the value of this line. For the moment, it display all the values

[image: linehcart guideline]

How can I display only the value when there is one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the perfect solution, but you can fill the values of the 1st line with `null` value from *dateB* to *dateC*

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lBKFld?p=preview)

Comment: Here you have passed null as point value. So it is showing **N/A**. But the graph is not joined. For **null** values it is showing empty point, show the line points are not connected. i need to connect those line and need to remove the point in tooltip or need to show **N/A**. See my code http://plnkr.co/edit/WbIe62ZcBbbuG00SbpLE?p=preview

Comment: This same thing is referenced here: https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/1897 
I have a similar issue, I need to show timestamp and a value on the tooltip for every datapoint and all have different timelines. Therefore this is not the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to solve this three ways.

1. First one is the solution mentioned: add null to fill the values.
2. Use content generator to create custom tooltip, and useInteractiveGuideline should be set to false

   ```
        tooltip: {
         contentGenerator: (e) => {
           return '<h1>Hello</h1>';
         }
       }
   ```
3. If you don't get proper data in the tooltip event, try with callback and get event data:

   ```
   callback(chart) {
     if (chart && chart.interactiveLayer) {
       const tooltip = chart.interactiveLayer.tooltip;
       tooltip.gravity('s');
       tooltip.contentGenerator(event => '<h1>Hello</h1>');
     }
   }
   ```