# nvd3 remove tooltip content for empty points

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using nvd3 line chart graph and used `useInteractiveGuideline: true`. So all the points has plotted in tooltip for the particular date.

Here is the issue i am facing, In first & Second point have two values, so tooltip is showing legend name and the two values for the both dates and the values.

The issue is in the third date, i am having only one point in the third line but it is showing the third point value with another point value.

Graph second line ends in 7th date,  but it is showing 7th date value till at the end of the graph.

I need to show only the point that has value.

So from 8th date tooltip need to show only one point in tooltip. Here is my nvd3 graph options,

```
  $scope.options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'lineChart',
      height: 450,
      margin: {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 45,
        left: 45
      },
      duration: 500,
      useInteractiveGuideline: true,
      xAxis: {
        axisLabel: 'Time (ms)',
        showMaxMin: false,
        tickFormat: function(d) {
          return d3.format(',f')(d);
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        axisLabel: 'Y Axis',
        axisLabelDistance: -20,
        tickFormat: function(d) {
          return d3.format(',.1f')(d);
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Here is the complete demo of my code

Demo : [Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/WbIe62ZcBbbuG00SbpLE?p=preview)

[Duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40976656/angular-nvd3-interactive-guideline-show-too-much-data) in this link they have passed null as point value. So it is showing **N/A**. But the graph is not joined. For `null` values it is showing empty point, show the line points are not connected. i need to connect those line and need to remove the point in tooltip or need to show **N/A**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular nvd3 interactive guideline show too much data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40976656/angular-nvd3-interactive-guideline-show-too-much-data)

Comment: @TimB it's kind of same, but for me there is no value after the 7th date. but tooltip is showing the 7th value to the balance dates.

Comment: Exactly, like [that](http://plnkr.co/edit/D9YTEkyVIslVg0E74F9J?p=preview)

Comment: :) @TimB, So where they have controlled the tool tip empty values, above example shows as **N/A**  for empty values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have inserted a condition to verify `xAxis` label and the tooltip value. Tooltip only added the matched `xAxis` index.

I used the condition as like `d.value !== p.data.x`. Here `p.data.x` is xAxis label. `d.value` is tooltip label. if both the values are not matched i removed the data. 
In the library find the following code,

```
trowEnter.append("td")
            .classed("value",true)
            .html(function(p, i) { return valueFormatter(p.value, i) });
```

and replace it as ,

```
trowEnter.append("td")
              .classed("value",true)
              .html(function(p,i) {  
               if (d.value !== p.data.x) {this.parentNode.style.display = "none";}
               return valueFormatter(p.value,i) 
            });
```

It will remove not matched contents in the tooltip.